# What does this condition written in bitwise operators really do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What does the following condition effectively check in C :

```
if(a & (1<<b))
```

I have been wracking my brains but I can't find a pattern. 
Any help?
Also I have seen this used a lot in competitive programming, could anyone explain when and why this is used?

Comment: "Is `b`th bit set in `a`?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is checking whether the `b`th bit of `a` is set.

`1<<b` will shift over a single set bit `b` times so that only one bit in the `b`th position is set.

Then the `&` will perform a bitwise and.  Since we already know the only bit that is set in `1<<b`, either it is set in `a`, in which case we get `1<<b`, or it isn't, in which case we get `0`.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical terms, this condition verifies if `a`'s binary representation contains 2<sup>b</sup>. In terms of bits, this checks if `b`'s bit of `a` is set to `1` (the number of the least significant bit is zero).

Recall that shifting `1` to the left by `b` positions produces a mask consisting of all zeros and a single `1` in position `b` counting from the right. A value of this mask is 2<sup>b</sup>.

When you perform a bitwise "AND" with such a mask, the result would be non-zero if, and only if, `a`'s binary representation contains 2<sup>b</sup>.

Comment: I don't understand the part :" if a's binary representation contains $2^b$ "

Comment: @HarshAgarwal Binary representation of a positive integer number is a sum of non-negative powers of 2. Each bit corresponds to 2^p, where `p` is that bit's number counting from the least significant one. For example, 5 is `101`, or 2^0 + 2^2 = 1+4 = 5.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say for example `a = 12 (binary: 1100)` and you want to check that the third bit (binaries are read from right to left) is set to 1, to do that you can use `&` bitwise operator which work as following:

```
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

To check if the third bit in `a` is set to 1 we can do:

```
1100
0100 &
------
0100 (4 in decimal) True
```

if `a = 8 (binary: l000)` on the other hand:

```
1000
0100 &
------
0000 (0 in decimal) False
```

Now to get the `0100` value we can right shift 1 by 2 (1 << 2) wich will append two zeros from the right and we'll get `100`, in binaries left trailing zeros doesn't change the value so `100` is the same as `0100`.